# Proving that a group $G$ which has no proper subgroups must be cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

If a group $\displaystyle G$ has no proper subgroups then it is to be proven that $\displaystyle G$ is cyclic.

I am not allowed to use Lagrange's theorem or the concept of order of an element in a group.

I proceeded as follows:

If $\displaystyle G=\{e\}$, then the theorem is trivially true.

So let's consider the case when $\displaystyle G\neq \{e\}$. It follows that $\displaystyle G$ has at least one non-identity element $\displaystyle a\in \ G$.

Now I claim that $\displaystyle G\setminus \langle a\rangle =\emptyset $.

Proof: On the contrary, suppose that $\displaystyle G\setminus \langle a\rangle \neq \emptyset $.

Let $\displaystyle x\in G\setminus \langle a\rangle $. It is known that $ $$\displaystyle \langle a\rangle \subset G$ is a subgroup of $\displaystyle G$ however since $\displaystyle (b\in G)\land (b\notin \langle a\rangle)$, it follows that $\displaystyle \langle a\rangle $ is a proper subgroup. This contradicts the given hypothesis that $\displaystyle G$ has no proper subgroups.

Therefore, $\displaystyle G\setminus \langle a\rangle =\emptyset $. It follows that $\displaystyle G =( G\setminus \langle a\rangle ) \cup \langle a\rangle =\emptyset \cup \langle a\rangle =\langle a\rangle $.

This proves that $\displaystyle G$ is cyclic.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: @Angelo: Thanks, I request one clarification: If $G$ is say $\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ then I have assumed that let $b\in G$ and then gone ahead proving $G=\langle b \rangle$ but not every element of $G$ can be a generator. Please correct me here, if I am wrong.

Comment: @Koro indeed, you only proved that $G$ has to be cyclic. But not every cyclic group has the property of not having proper subgroups. And your $\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ is in fact a counterexample: $\{e,a^2\}$ is a proper subgroup. In fact, $G$ has no proper subgroups precisely when $|G|$ is a prime number. But to conclude that you need Lagrange's theorem together with Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @freakish: I was thinking that in my example above: if I had chosen $b=a^2\in G$, then straightaway I would have got a contradiction by skipping $a$ in the beginning. And as your comment mentions, I'm proving the theorem one way not conversely so Lagrange's not required. Thank you! :)

Comment: I think you can streamline your proof a bit. Let $a\neq e\in G$, then $\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ (easy to check). However since $G$ by assumption has no non-trivial subgroups, you're forced to conclude that either $\langle a\rangle = e$ or $\langle a\rangle = G$. Clearly the former cannot be the case since $a\neq e \in \langle a\rangle$, so $\langle a\rangle = G$. This is the same argument you've made, just a bit more straightforward. Good work though! As you have guessed, this statement is a lot stronger than just $G$ being cyclic since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ fails the assumptions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: That makes sense. Thank you! :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Sir, any hint on proving order of $G$ prime (in this case)without using concept of order of element of a group, Lagrange’s theorem and Cauchy theorem?

Comment: Sure: If $G$ is cyclic - which we've shown - then (assuming $G$ is finite), $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$. (Map generator $a$ to $1$ (not $0$) and prove it's isomorphic.) For composite $n = pq$, $\langle p\rangle$ is non-trivial. (Why?) Do you see how this answers your question?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Sir, thanks a lot but I’m afraid isomorphism is not allowed because isomorphism topic will be covered later in the book.  Let me explain my working also and where I’m having difficulty.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: 
I thought along these lines: Let order of G be m and for contradiction suppose that m is composite. And therefore there exist some primes $p_1,p_2, \cdots, p_k$ such that $m=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$. Following which I claimed that $\{e,a,…, a^{p_1-1}\}$ is a subgroup but then got stuck.
If I can prove $ \{e,a,…, a^{p_1-1}\}$ is a subgroup then I am done. But I’m having difficulty here ☹️

Comment: Ah this is basically the same idea as what I was saying actually just made a little more complicated by breaking $m$ down in terms of its prime decomposition! Make it easier on yourself by letting $m = pq$, then consider $a^p$. If $a^p = e$, then you're done already (since $\langle a\rangle$ would be a non-trivial subgroup as its order is at most $p$ which is less than $m$), otherwise you can see that $\langle a^p\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $q$ which is less than $m$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Sir, I suppose that in $m=pq$ both $p,q$ are not prime. I'll think on this. Thanks a lot for your guidance :)

Comment: @Koro it doesn't actually matter to the argument for what it's worth. It's really that it is composite at all, no need to break it down into prime factors.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Noted. To have more space, I've written down complete proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134590/proving-that-a-group-with-no-proper-subgroups-must-be-of-prime-order-without-usi. I request your review here. Thanks a lot sir :)