# Proving that a group with no proper subgroups must be of prime order without using Lagrange theorem and under other restrictions.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

This is further to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133859/proving-that-a-group-g-which-has-no-proper-subgroups-must-be-cyclic?noredirect=1%5C#comment8552341%5C_4133859) that I asked earlier. Based on suggestions/hints in the comments, I propose this proof for proving that a group $\displaystyle G$ with no proper subgroup is of prime order. I am not allowed to use Lagrange's theorem, Cauchy theorem, concept of order of an element of a group, isomorphisms.

I proceed as follows:

It's already been proven in my last post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133859/proving-that-a-group-g-which-has-no-proper-subgroups-must-be-cyclic?noredirect=1%5C#comment8552341%5C_4133859) that $\displaystyle G$ must be cyclic. If $\displaystyle G=\{e\}$, then the given statement is wrong as $\displaystyle 1$ is not a prime.

So let's consider the non-trivial case when $\displaystyle ord( G)  >1$.

Of course $\displaystyle G$ can be considered finite, if not finite then talking about order of $\displaystyle G$ in terms of prime does not make sense. So let order of $\displaystyle G=m >1$ and suppose on the contrary that $\displaystyle m$ is not a prime. It follows that $m$ can be written as product of $\displaystyle p$ and $\displaystyle q$ such that
\begin{equation}
m=pq,\ \ ( p\geq 2) \land ( q\geq 2) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Let $a\in G$ be a non-identity element.
Either $\displaystyle a^{p} =1$ or $\displaystyle a^{p} \neq 1$.

Case 1: $\displaystyle a^{p} =1$

Let's consider the set $\displaystyle \{a,a^{2} ,a^{3} ,\cdots ,a^{p} \}$, which is clearly a proper subgroup of $\displaystyle G$ so this case is not possible.

Case 2: $\displaystyle a^{p} \neq 1$

Let's consider the set $\displaystyle S=\{a^{pi} :\ i\in \mathbb{Z} \}$, which is clearly a subgroup of $\displaystyle G.$ In$\displaystyle A=\{a^{p} ,a^{2p} ,\cdots ,a^{mp} ,\ a^{( m+1) p} \}$ at least two elements must be the same as $\displaystyle G$ is finite. For some $\displaystyle a^{ip} \in A$ there exists $\displaystyle a{^{\ }}^{jp} \in A$ such that
\begin{equation}
a^{ip} =a{^{\ }}^{jp} ,\ j >i\geq 1 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
It follows that $\displaystyle a^{( j-i) p} =e=a^{kp}$, where $\displaystyle k=j-i\geq 1$ and $\displaystyle k\leq m+1-j< m\Longrightarrow 1\leq k< m$

Now for any $\displaystyle i >k$, we have by Euclid's division lemma that $\displaystyle i=kq+r$, where $\displaystyle 0\leq r< k$ and therefore $\displaystyle a^{pi} =a^{ri}$ and $\displaystyle S$ boils down to the set $\displaystyle S=\{a^{p} ,a^{2p} ,\cdots ,a^{( k-1) p} ,e\}$, which is clearly a subgroup of order $\displaystyle k < m$ and therefore $\displaystyle S$ is a proper subgroup of $\displaystyle G$, which is not possible.

Therefore by contradiction our assumption in $\displaystyle ( 1)$ is wrong and therefore $\displaystyle m$ must be a prime.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your proof can be a lot simpler for the case where $G$ is finite and generated by $a$. Suppose that $|G|$ is composite and equal to $pq$ where $1 < p < |G|$ and $1 < q < |G|$. Consider the element $g = a^q$. Then $g \neq 1$ and $g^p = a^{pq} = a^{|G|} = 1$, so $g$ has order no larger than $p$. Thus $G$ has a proper subgroup $\langle g \rangle$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Note that you still have to show that $G$ can't be infinite.

Comment: @Bungo: That's amazing. Thank you! In my proof 1) I nowhere used $q$ and 2) I think there is an issue with my case 2 also ($k$ can equal to $m$), which I realized through an answer (now deleted) to this post.

Comment: @Bungo: Why? The fact that $G$ even has prime order inherently means that $G$ must be finite. Right? As there is no point in talking about prime or parity of an infinite order.

Comment: It's not a given fact that $G$ has prime order, that's what you have to show! This means that you have to exclude the other two possibilities: (1) $G$ is finite and has composite order, or (2) $G$ is infinite.

Comment: @Bungo: I thought that: whenever we say prove that $G$ has (say prime, or odd, or even  order ) then that $G$ must be finite as if not then there is no point in talking about prime/even/odd order of G as infinity is not prime, even or odd etc. Please help  me understand this if the earlier statement is not correct. If not correct, then I'll try proving that $G$ can't be infinite also. Thanks a lot. I'll also request you to see paragraph no 4 starting with "of course we can consider $G$ to be finite...". Is something wrong with this assertion?

Comment: Generally, a problem statement like "prove that $G$ has prime order" means "prove that $G$ is finite and has prime order" if you don't already have the hypothesis that $G$ is finite. Whether this is required in your case depends on context. If this were an exercise in a book about finite group theory, then probably all groups are assumed finite. But if you're working in a context where groups could be infinite, then probably "prove that it's prime" is intended to be mean "prove that it's finite and prime." If you have an instructor, you might want to check with them to be sure.

Comment: @Bungo: What you said makes sense. I would like to inform that this is an exercise problem. The problem is in two parts: 1) If G has no proper subgroups then $G$ is cyclic (I managed to prove this one). 2). If $G$ has no proper subgroups, then prove that G is cyclic of prime order. G is not given to be finite. So I understand it now that finite is also to be proven. Also, till this chapter cyclic group has been defined as      $\{a^i:\text{ i is integer}\}$ so I am not sure whether I can use $a^{|G|}=1$, which I know is a corollary of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @Bungo: I have written an answer now. I request your review of the same. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is noted that the proof in OP is not complete yet and has some errors also which I'll try to fix up in this answer.

The statement to be proven is this: If a group has no proper subgroups then the group is cyclic of order $\displaystyle p$.

The group will have concept of order $\displaystyle p$ (finite) only if the group is also finite. So first let's prove that $\displaystyle G$ is finite.

**Claim:** $\displaystyle G$ is finite.

**Proof:** Suppose that $\displaystyle G$ is infinite group. Let $\displaystyle g\in G$ be a non-identity element and we consider the subset $\displaystyle A_{g} =\{g^{i} :i\in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

It is plain that all elements in $\displaystyle A_{g}$ are distinct for if any two elements in $\displaystyle A_{g} \ $are same (say $\displaystyle a^{i} =a^{j}$ then $\displaystyle a^{i-j} =1$, where $\displaystyle i >j$ and then it can be verified that $\displaystyle \{1,a,a,\cdots ,a^{i-j-1} \}$ is a subgroup of $\displaystyle G$.

It follows that $\displaystyle G=A_{g}$ and similarly, $\displaystyle G=A_{g^{2}}$.

**Claim:** $\displaystyle g\notin A_{g^{2}}$.

**Proof:** Suppose on the contrary that $\displaystyle \exists i\in \mathbb{Z} -\{0\}$ such that $\displaystyle g=g^{2i}$. It follows that $\displaystyle g^{2i-1} =1\Longrightarrow \{1,g,g^{2} ,\cdots ,g^{2i-2} \}$ is a proper subgroup of $\displaystyle G$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $\displaystyle g\notin A_{g^{2}}$, which is a contradiction as $\displaystyle A_{g^{2}} =G$. Therefore, our assumption that $\displaystyle G\ $is infinite is not correct. It follows that $\displaystyle G$ is finite.

Having suitably dealt with the first part, it remains to prove that $\displaystyle G$ is cyclic and has order $\displaystyle p$. It has already been proven in my earlier post (linked in the OP) that $\displaystyle G$ is cyclic.

Suppose on the contrary that $\displaystyle G$ is of composite order $\displaystyle t$. Let $\displaystyle t=mn$, where both $\displaystyle m,n$ are at least equal to $\displaystyle 2.$

Let $\displaystyle g\in G$ be a non-identity element. Consider the set $\displaystyle A=\{g,g^{2} ,\cdots ,g^{mn} ,\ g^{mn+1} \}$. Clearly at least two elements of $\displaystyle A$ must be the same (if not then $\displaystyle G$ has $\displaystyle mn+1$ elements resulting immediately in contradiction). Let $\displaystyle g^{i} =g^{j}$ for some $\displaystyle i,j$ such that $\displaystyle 1\leq i< j\leq mn+1\Longrightarrow 1\leq j-i\leq mn$

It follows that $\displaystyle g^{k} =1$, where $\displaystyle k=j-i$.

Now $\displaystyle k\neq s$ for any $\displaystyle s< mn$ for if $\displaystyle k=s< mn$  then $\displaystyle \{1,g,g^{2} ,\cdots ,g^{s-1} \}$ is a proper subgroup which is contradiction so $\displaystyle k$. So $\displaystyle k=mn$. And it follows that
\begin{equation}
a^{mn} =1 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Let's consider the set $\displaystyle \langle g^{m} \rangle =\{g^{mi} :\ i\in \mathbb{Z} \}\ $. Now if $\displaystyle i >n$, then by Euclid's division lemma, we must have $\displaystyle q$ and $\displaystyle r$ such that $\displaystyle i=nq+r$, where $\displaystyle r< n$ and it follows that $\displaystyle a^{mi} =a^{r}$ (using (1)).

For negative $\displaystyle i\in \mathbb{Z}$, we add $\displaystyle mn$ to the power so that $\displaystyle \langle g^{m} \rangle =\{g^{m} ,g^{2m} ,\cdots ,g^{( n-1) m} ,\ g^{nm} \}$. It is clear that this subgroup has only $\displaystyle n$ elements ($\displaystyle < mn)$, which is a contradiction as $\displaystyle G$ can't have a proper subgroup.

Therefore, we conclude by contradiction that $\displaystyle G\ ( \neq \{e\})$ is of prime order.

Comment: I think this proof is very good. I really enjoyed the part showing it was finite, and the rest of it was in my opinion quite straightforward. In the original post issues have been pointed out, so I won't look there, but this answer looks very good to me. I'm just very happy with the first part, it's a brilliant argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot madam @TeresaLisbon for taking time to review. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are few gaps in the proof.

First you are not given that $G$ is finite. So you have to prove that $G$ cannot be infinite before you prove that $G$ must be of prime order.

Second, in Case 2, $G$ is finite does not imply that there exist two identical elements in $A$. In fact this is because $A$ is a subset of $G$ and $|A|=m+1>m=|G|$.

Third, in Case 2, it may happen that $i=1$ and $j=m+1$, which implies that $k=j-i=m$.

Comment: Thanks for response :). I would like to say that 1) the fact that we are even talking about order of G means that G must be finite so no proof required there per se. 2) No. Please note that $m$ is the order of $G$ so its subset $A$ can't have more cardinality than $G$. 3) That is not possible because $k$ is strictly less than $m$ as I have shown in case (2) though I have skipped some details there. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro (1) From what I know, the order of $G$ is the cardinality of $G$, so it is possible for the order of $G$ to be infinite. (2) Yes, but in your proof you only stated that $G$ is finite. (3) May I know how you show that $k\leq m+1-j$?

Comment: 1) If G were infinite, could you really say whether that infinite is prime or not. It does not make sense and therefore as I mentioned in my post, G has to be finite that is our proof makes sense if G is finite.  2)&3): Following 1), note that $j\gt i\ge 1$, you would agree that $k=j-i\ge 1$ and that $1-j$ is negative. Now, I think you are right in that $k$ can equal to $m$ also. I confused $i$ with $j$. I'll rethink this one.

Comment: @Koro If $G$ is infinite, then $|G|$ cannot be prime order so the statement is false. But I think this does not mean that you can assume that $G$ is finite because you want to prove the statement. To prove that the statement is correct, you should prove that $G$ cannot be infinite.

Comment: The point is that: if $|G|$ is infinite, that case does not concern us as there is no point in talking about its order being prime or not. So we can consider finite $G$. We need not prove that. Our theorem is valid for finite groups. Meanwhile, I'm working on to fix the proof (that k=m+1 part).

Comment: I have slightly modify the language to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Koro Sorry that I still do not agree with your point. I will suggest you to search other sources for the proofs of this statement.

Comment: I understand now what you meant by proving $G$ to be finite. Thanks a lot for reviewing my proof. That's how I knew that I overlooked an error. Thanks a lot. +1.          I have meanwhile posted my full solution based on  suggestions in comments. I request your review on that also :)